# ArrayList is still empty after adding data decoded from JSon object

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have this java code in Android Studio, when creating new Majors and print m.getName().. They are printed and data is decoded correctly from the Json object, but after adding data to the ArrayList majorsArrayList, it's still empty and data isn't added.

Here where I checked for ArrayList (in onCreate()) and the result is: ARRAYLIST[]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMajors);
        getmajors("Al-Kafaat University","Faculty of Pedagogy","faculty","en");
        System.out.println("ARRAYLIST"+majorsArrayList);
        recycler_majorAdapter recyclerMajorAdapter=new recycler_majorAdapter(this,majorsArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerMajorAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        System.out.println("ARRAYLIST"+majorsArrayList);}
```

And here is the function getmajors()

```
private void getmajors(String uni, String faculty, String dest, String lang)
{
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://...", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray opp =new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i< opp.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject pollObject= opp.getJSONObject(i);
                    String major=pollObject.getString("maj");
                    String university=pollObject.getString("univ");
                    int id=pollObject.getInt("id");
                    Majors m=new Majors(major,university, id);
                    System.out.println(m.getName());
                    System.out.println(m.getUniversity());
                    System.out.println(m.getId());
                    majorsArrayList.add(m);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you use majorsArrayList and check for empty.

Comment: `(No adapter because I am using RecyclerView)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, just added the two lines in onCreate():

```
recycler_majorAdapter recyclerMajorAdapter=new recycler_majorAdapter(this,majorsArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerMajorAdapter);
```

to the getmajors() function after the for loop.